# Importing bundles with Magmi... Easiest way?

Tags: magmi

Lost all my bundles... Created an excel sheet of all my bundle skus, and the sku that needs to be bundled in it.

Wondering the easiest way to upload a bundle in Magmi. I see a bunch of way that incorporate coding the crap out of cells...I see a bunch of paid extensions that basically do that same thing, nothing that automatically formats.

I attached my CSV wondering if someone could show me how I could format it so when I upload the colummn "att_rootsku" is bundled inside the sku column.

---

This is what my csv looks like. Any help would be greatly appreciated....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

magmi doesn't support importing bundles. You can use AvS_FastSimpleImport, ApiImport or uRapidFlow Pro for that.